# Crystal Reports printing values on multiple pages rather than condensing all values into one field on one page

Tags: crystal-reports

[image]

I have a SQL table extracting information from another table in multiple places example in link is above.

When I create the report, I want to make sure all information from {TABLE1.COL2} shows in one field, listed.  So it should read out:

GREEN

YELLOW

However, with the report I created, it puts Green on one page, then creates a second page to show yellow.

I have it linked using a Left Outer Join where COL1 on both tables must be equal, attempted setting a sort field using Record Sort Expert, and set the field to Can Grow with 0 as my max.

I know this can be done as I've seen it done in other reports, but can't seem to replicate it here for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, table should like this:

Comment: Just check if New page after is being set for that detail section in report.

Comment: It is not checked, just confirmed.

Comment: To clarify the issue, all other fields populate without issue.  It replicates all the data to a second page, with the only difference between pages 1 and 2 being GREEN and YELLOW listed under color.  I want to return one page with all data, with GREEN and YELLOW being listed rather than on two pages.

Comment: I was able to resolve this, it was formatting on the report. I had included extra items in the details section, rather than in the group.  When I moved the additional items out of details, it is showing in a list mode now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this, it was formatting on the report. I had included extra items in the details section, rather than in the group. When I moved the additional items out of details, it is showing in a list mode now.